# Subsonic3 LINQ Left Outer Join

Tags: vb.net, linq, subsonic3, left-join

I am using Subsonic3 and would like to get a Left Outer Join between two tables. Here is the tested SQL

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM vwVendor a
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.pubvenmap b
on a.vend_no = b.vend_no
where b.vend_no is null
```

I am stuck at

```
Dim vendors = From v In vwVendor.All()
Join m in pubvenmap.All() On v.vend_no Equals m.vend_no
```

***UPDATED***
I also tried the following

```
Dim vendors = New SubSonic.Query.Select(SubSonic.Query.Aggregate.GroupBy("vend_no")).From(Of vwVendor).LeftOuterJoin(Of mac_pubvenmap)().ExecuteTypedList(Of vwVendor)()
```

but get the error

> A first chance exception of type
>   'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in SubSonic.Core.dll

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and .NET 4.0...could this be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the LINQ expression Albin posted gives you trouble (SubSonic's LINQ provider is not as complete as Linq2Sql or Entity Framework's), be aware that you can use [SubSonic's fluent query objects](http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Active_Record_Fluent_Query) to also perform a Left Outer Join:

```
SubSonic.SqlQuery query = new NorthwindDB.Select
  .From<Customer>()
  .LeftOuterJoin<Order>();
  query.Aggregates  = new List<Aggregate> { 
    new Aggregate(CustomerTable.CustomerNameColumn, AggregateFunction.GroupBy) };
```

Comment: I've been trying that but I keep getting error  'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in SubSonic.Core.dll

Comment: Can you edit your question and show the code you are using, the little bit you do have in there seems incomplete, and there's none there with this method.  Also, posting a more complete stack trace can help us find the exact issue quicker.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, are normal queries working for you?  If I recall correctly you were having a similar issue with SubSonic yesterday regarding using Views.  Just trying to rule things out.

Comment: Normal queries are working fine. That's the only piece of code I am calling on my form load and I am trying to bind the vendors to a dropdownlist

Comment: Simple one like this works 'Dim vendors = From v In Accounting.vwVendorActiveDB.All()
        '              Select v

Answer (score 0):

All common LINQ constructs are examplified at [LINQ 101 Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb688088.aspx). Specifically in this case [Left Outer Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/bb737909#lojoin).

If I got my rusty VB right your code will be like this.

```
Dim vendors = From v In vwVendor.All() _
            Group Join m in pubvenmap.All() On v.vend_no Equals m.vend_no Into Group _
            From m In Group.DefaultIfEmpty() _
            Select v
```

Comment: I get the error A first chance exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Core.dll